# Get a zip file from backend

Tags: angular, nestjs, jszip

I'm trying to generate files in the backend, then return a zip file containing all these files.

The backend function looks like this:

```js
  import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

  @Get('encrypt/all')
  async encryptAllRecipes() {
    const zip: JSZip = new JSZip();
    const allRecipes: RecipeEntity[] = await this.listAllRecipes();
    for(const recipe of allRecipes) {
      const encryptedRecipeStr: string = await this.encryptRecipe(recipe);
      zip.file(`${recipe.name}.enc`, encryptedRecipeStr);
    }
    
    const buffer: Buffer = await (zip.generateAsync({type:"nodebuffer"}, function updateCallback(metadata) {
      console.log("progression: " + metadata.percent.toFixed(2) + " %");
    }));

    return buffer;
  }
```

The answer of this function looks this way (I truncated it using "..." inside because it was too big)

```json
{"type":"Buffer","data":[80,75,3,4,...,0,0,0,19,0,109,4,0,0,121,17,0,0,0,0]}
```

Then, in the frontend, I would like to download the zip file:

```js
exportAllToEncryptedFile() {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders();
  const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
  return this._httpRequestsManager
    .get(`${this._constants.encryptAllRecipesAddress}`, {headers, params, responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
        const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'arraybuffer' });
        saveAs(blob, `encryptedRecipes.zip`);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
}
```

The file cannot be read as a zip, it contains the json returned by the backend. I've tried many things, among which:

- Returning the buffer using a base64 encoding from the backend, and decoding this string from the front
- Using the "responseType" with 'blob' and 'arraybuffer'
- Storing the response.data field in the file, instead of the whole response
- Defining a header's content type, to 'application/zip', to 'text/plain', to 'multipart/form-data'

I'm not very experienced with http queries. How could I manage this?

Thank you.

Edit: From the backend, if I write the buffer to a file directly, the resulting file is correct.

```js
fs.writeFile('C:\\ziptests\\testBlob.zip', buffer, () => {
   console.log('file written');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier solution to the downloading of zip files is to create the file in the backend and send the path(as a link) to frontend and just have a href with the link so that the browser initiates the download